# Testing game on XBox360?

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

Im about to convert a game I made from one language to XNA. Do I have to pay Microsoft to be able to test it on my Xbox360? Im not looking to upload it to the market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a paid membership is required to debug / test an XNA game on the Xbox 360 console.

Comment: Do you know if coding for an XNA Windows game is the same?

Comment: No: running, compiling and debugging a normal XNA game on a PC is absolutely free.

Comment: Also you can use Xbox controllers on the PC. So there's no real benefit to running it on the 360 if you don't intend to publish it there.

Answer (score 0):

You need a paid subscription to deploy the game to your xbox.

Unless you're a student, in which case you can sign up for a student account, which is a free one year subscription (I believe you can't publish it on market place though).

The game should work both on PC and on XBox, but the hardware will be different and some XBOX Live features (such as avatar) will not show up on the PC debug.